# Would it be possible to track another android device

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I am working on building an application that tracks a GPS enabled android device. It is sort of a service to track local taxi network around my place.

now my question is Would it be possible to track another device through the android API, with the consent of the owner of the device?

I am using google maps API to display the map and markers.

**EDIT:**

To be precise, i would like to track the location and if possible the movement of another GPS enabled device from the user's phone. Lets say the User clicks on a button to know the nearest location of a taxi which is equipped with an android powered GPS device, the user should be given the location of that nearest taxi on his map.

I would like to equip the users to query the location of the taxi through my app.

So would this require a central server to which the GPS in the Taxis send their location information periodically and the user's device will query the server for the Taxi's location?

Or can this be achieved without a dedicated server and by using Google's location service to query the other device through my app?

I went through some docs in the Google play services but they seem to track the location of device which has installed the app rather than getting the location of another remote device.

Comment: Please explain completely and precisely what "track another device through the android API" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare thx for the response. I have updated my question with more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. with the details you have given ... I think one way to do it would to use some sort of cloud where you store the locations (in a database or anything that suits your app),, according to your description I feel you can split users of your app into two categories,

a>users b> taxis

1. you need to collect their locations periodically and update the data base
2. you should update the content ( location shown to user ) in app by getting data from data base periodically based on user location and with a predefined radius to show all taxis near users location
3. then refresh the relevant views based on the category of user, so that the users can see taxis near to them

suggestion: I would suggest you to use cloud server like Parse which makes it very easy to save locations and also provide a very efficient way to retrieve it with just few lines of code.. hope this helps

*Update* ::
As of my knowledge I think this cant be done without a server since you need some place where you can efficiently save the user data (locations etc) so that you can present the relevant details based on the data saved on server.

Comment: i thought the same. Querying another device's location freely without any restriction would also possess serious security threats. Thx for ur answer.. :)

Answer (score 2):

What I did and would advice you to this is, firstly my project was to make an uber like app but specifically for buses. My app tracks the location and movement of other Android devices by storing the current location on a realtime database like firebase. There are 2 apps, the user app and the bus app. The bus app sends and updates its current location on to a realtime online database every 50 milliseconds which is firebase. Then the user app retrieves the location from the database and sets a marker onto the map. I hope you understood and I got to help you